# Trying to remove cell border on a data table but the tag, "cell-border" is not working

Tags: html-table, datatables

Following these instrucitons for having a data table with no borders: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes#Table-classes

I try "cell-border" but it does not get rid of the border.

To avoid pasting all the code, here is the site I am trying to remove the borders from:

https://www.AudiobookReviews.com

Answer (score 0):

Morning! Your table has a fair few borders, which is where you're running into trouble I guess, rather than the `cell-border`? This SCSS:

```
#example {
  border: none;
  th {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
  }
  td {
    border: none;
  }
}
```

transpiles into this CSS:

```
#example {
  border: none;
}
#example th {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
#example td {
  border: none;
}
```

That removes all the borders I could see by inspecting the table in the developer tools. In fact, that's the take away from this answer, take a look within the developer tools and check what style is being applied to what element. More information here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Hope that helps - I think you only want the border removing from the table cells so perhaps only use the CSS for the `td`